# What are the trade-offs between different values of resistance for a wheatstone bridge?

Tags: resistance, load-cell, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

I have a loadcell with a bridge resistance of 10k and I've asked the manufacturer for a new design with RTDs and a slight mechanical change, and as a consequence, the manufacturer's proposed new design has a decreased bridge resistance from 10k to 5k (they are modifying the bridge layout and I assume 5k makes the design more achievable, because of *reasons*).

Nothing else is expected to change, other than a potential drop in sensitivity - perhaps down from 2mV/V to 1.3mV/V.
So far I'm considering self-heating and power consumption; an additional 2.5mW at 5V excitation in my application.

**What, if any, are the other trade-offs of changing the bridge resistance (increasing or decreasing)?**

Existing design spec:

[image]

Comment: What's the new design spec (side by side please).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a datasheet or spec for the newer version - it's currently being prototyped and characterised by the manufacturer. It has been mentioned in conversation that little is expected to change, except perhaps the rated output sensitivity as mentioned, but that's an unknown. I've also asked if the manufacturer can look at improving the temperature coefficient, as they suggested an improvement might be possible with the revised layout, but no values have been given. I appreciate it's all rather anecdotal.

Comment: In theory, the bridge must match the sensor median value, for max sensitivity... in practice, some sensors are lower R which helps to attenuate CM noise.